# Hangman game trouble with GUI

Tags: java, swing, list, for-loop, jlabel

Im new in Java socket and i try to develop a small game through socket, everything is ok on server but in client , i got trouble when i create a list of JLabel to show a letter "_" for each letter of word

Ok i show my code you will see what trouble i got.

my Snippett code like this:

```
List<JLabel>labels;

 private void getWordLabels(String word){
        char[] chars  = word.toCharArray();
        System.out.println(chars);
        int gapBetweenLetter = 300/chars.length;
        labels = new ArrayList<JLabel>();

        for(int i =0; i< chars.length ;i++){

           // JLabel l = new JLabel("_");
            labels.add(new JLabel());
            labels.get(i).setText("_");
            //this.add(l);
            //l.setBounds(10, 10, 10, 10);
            //l.show();
            this.removeAll();
            this.revalidate();
            this.repaint();
            labels.get(i).setBounds((i*gapBetweenLetter) + 10, 100, 50, 50);

            this.add(labels.get(i));

            labels.get(i).show();
             initComponents();

        /* labels.add(new JLabel("_"));
        this.add(labels.get(i));
        //labels[i].setText("_");
        System.out.println(labels.get(i));
        * */


    }
}
    }
```

but i got null pointer exception, i don't know why?

Someone can help me or show what wrong in my code.

Thank you!

Comment: That would be impossible. The only way there could be an NPE on that line would be if the `ArrayList` variable `labels` were null, but it can't be, since the preceding lines succeed. Double-check your error messages!

Comment: Can you tell us what the `add` method of your class does?

Comment: @Diego I think his class extends JFrame or a container and it's just the method add from Container

Comment: @Dynguss as i mention in my code, you can see my comment on my code snippet above.
ErnestFriedman-Hill: can you explan more about that?
Diego: my class extends from JPanel and this Panel add JLabel into JPanel

Comment: Well I can't reproduce sorry, working for me. Are you sure that it is this line that causing problem?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @talnicolas my stacktrace show it for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't see anything obvious, so I'd start by refactoring to

```
for(int i =0; i< chars.length ;i++){
        JLabel l = new JLabel("_");
        labels.add(l);
        this.add(l);
        //labels[i].setText("_");
        System.out.println(l);
    }
```

which may help you to see the problem. It also avoids repeating the get(i) [probably not expensive on an ArrayList, but still]

BTW: what type is 'this'?

Comment: as i told before "this" is a class extends from JPanel

Comment: Didn't notice that, but I kind of assumed it.

Comment: i can print 'l' but it not show on my panel, i use l.setBound but it not work

Comment: So none of the labels you create are visible?

Comment: @J2MENewBiew : In order for your JLabel to appear do `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on your JPanel after you write `this.add(l);`, that will allow them to be seen. It goes like this `panelObject.revalidate(); panelObject.repaint();`. Never use setBounds(...) or any size related method on components in swing. Let Layout Manager worry about that.

Comment: @GagandeepBay very much , but when i repaint it, i have to initial component because i remvoe all and repaint then re-initial all component inside jpanel. And one thing is it just paint one JLabel, not appropriate with letter of word, if my word is "Java" it just pain "_" we need 4 "_" instead of one, i was edit my code please check it

Comment: @J2MENewBiew this answer is correct, if it doesn't help you it's because of errors in your code _outside_ the snippet you hava shown. Either you show an sscce or you (most probably) nobody _can_ help you more - after all, magic globes are unreliable ;-)

Comment: thank you, i solve it by add it into jlabel because my background is jlabel